# Change tuple values into dataframe

Tags: dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe that looks like this (imaginary data for illustration):
[image]

I would like to transform these tuple paired(?) values like the following dataframe:

```
Date       Age      Sex       Height(cm)  ...
20150210   23       Female    209         ...
20150421   31       Male      301         ...
```

what could be the easiest way to transform it into the dataframe I desire without typing in every column names manually?

thanks.

Comment: How do you create this dataframe?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh first i had to perform Regex to extract those values then I created the above dataframe using dataframe.from_records, if I understood your question correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your original data is a list of list tuple. You can convert the inner list of tuple to dictionary, then pass it to `pd.DataFrame()` to create dataframe.

```py
data= [[('Date', '2015 02 10 '), ('Age', '  23'), ('Sex',   'Female'), ('Height(cm)', '209'), ('Weight(kg)',  '42.0')],
       [('Date', '2015 04 21 '), ('Age', '  31'), ('Sex',   'Male'  ), ('Height(cm)', '301'), ('Weight(kg)',  '69.0')],
       [('Date', '2015 04 21 '), ('Age', '  11'), ('Sex',   'Male'  ), ('Height(cm)', '150'), ('Weight(kg)',  '69.0')]]

df = pd.DataFrame(map(dict, data))
```

```
print(df)

         Date Age     Sex  Height(cm)  Weight(kg)
0  2015 02 10  23  Female         209        42.0
1  2015 04 21  31    Male         301        69.0
2  2015 04 21  11    Male         150        69.0
```

There seems extra whitespaces in your data, you can strip them with

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

You can also `strip` the extra spaces in creation

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in d.items()} for d in map(dict, data)])
```

If your `Date` key is the possible duplicate key, you can combine the value of duplicate key to a list. Then explode on that column to turn list into multi rows.

```py
import collections

data= [[('Date', '2015 02 10 '), ('Date', '2015 02 10 '), ('Age', '  23'), ('Sex',  'Female'), ('Height(cm)', '209'), ('Weight(kg)',  '42.0')],
       [('Date', '2015 04 21 '), ('Age', '  31'), ('Sex',   'Male'  ), ('Height(cm)', '301'), ('Weight(kg)',  '69.0')],
       [('Date', '2015 04 21 '), ('Age', '  11'), ('Sex',   'Male'  ), ('Height(cm)', '150'), ('Weight(kg)',  '69.0')]]

data_ = []
for list_of_tuple in data:
    c = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for a, b in list_of_tuple:
        c[a].append(b)

    data_.append(c.items())

df = pd.DataFrame(map(dict, data_))
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

```
print(df)

          Date   Age     Sex Height(cm) Weight(kg)
0  2015 02 10     23  Female        209       42.0
0  2015 02 10     23  Female        209       42.0
1  2015 04 21     31    Male        301       69.0
2  2015 04 21     11    Male        150       69.0
```

Comment: @WonChulChung What problem?

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works fantastically, I indeed had a list of list tuple. but i'm faced with an another problem.
I did not tell you the full story but besides the tuple examples above, I got multiple tuples with the same name (key) like ('Result', ' 23'), ('Result,' 42') ('Result, '43'). Your code seems to give me only ('Result, '43') as a final output. I want to keep all three "Result" tuples to be appearing in the dataframe.

Comment: @WonChulChung Could you post a sample data? list of list tuple contains same key?

Comment: @WonChulChung How many same key does you have? Only `Result` or more?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, I did end up trying to make an empty list then append individual values to the dataframe. I see the key solution seems to be the map() function. Thank you for your help, it solved my problem1